# mostrar imágenes asociadas a un mismo registro

Tags: php, pdo

estoy tratando de mostrar una consulta y en la misma mostrar las imágenes asociadas a ese registro, pero solo consigo que me muestro solo una imagen cuando no debería ser ya que si un registro tiene asociado tres imágenes debería mostrarlas todas pero como dije solo consigo que me devuelva solo una imagen,

```
`aquí mis tablas: 

 tabla: detalles_catagorias

 id, fk_categorias, precio, descripcion, detalles

 tabla: detalles_img

 id, fk_detalles_categorias, imagen`
```

mi consulta

```
 <?php


 $sql = "
 SELECT 
 detalles_categorias.id,
 detalles_categorias.fk_categorias,
 detalles_categorias.precio,
 detalles_categorias.descripcion,
 detalles_categorias.detalles,
 detalles_img.id,
 detalles_img.fk_detalles_categorias,
 detalles_img.imagen, GROUP_CONCAT(detalles_img.imagen SEPARATOR '----')
 FROM detalles_categorias INNER JOIN detalles_img ON   detalles_img.fk_detalles_categorias = detalles_categorias.id 
 WHERE detalles_img.fk_detalles_categorias = detalles_categorias.id
 GROUP BY detalles_img.fk_detalles_categorias";

 $consulta = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
 $consulta->execute(array(':id'=>$id,':fk_detalles_categorias'=>$id));
 if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
 $i=1;

 echo "<table  class='bordered responsive-table'>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th data-field='N&#186;'>N&#186;</th>
 <th data-field='Código'>categorias</th>
 <th data-field='Código'>precio</th>
 <th data-field='Código'>descripcion</th>
 <th data-field='Código'>detalles</th>
 <th data-field='Código'>imagenes</th>
 <th data-field='Operaciones'>Operaciones Administrador</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>";
 while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo "<tr>
<td align=center>$i</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['fk_categorias']}</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['precio']}</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['descripcion']}</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['detalles']}</td>
<td align=center><img src='../galerias/$linea[imagen]' class=responsive-img     circle center-align width=70px height=70px></td>
";
?>
<?php 
$imagen = explode("/", $linea[imagen]);
 //var_dump($imagen);
 ?>

 <?php
  echo "<td colspan='2'>
  <form action='actualizar_multiple.php' method='GET'> 
  <input type=hidden name=id value='$linea[id]'>
  <button class='btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 left  
  btn-small tooltipped' data-position='bottom'
  data-tooltip='Actualizar' type='submit' name='actualizar'>
  <i class='material-icons'>update</i>
  </button></form>

  <form action='consultar_seguros.php' method='POST'> 
  <input type=hidden name=id value='$linea[id]'>
  <button class='btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 left  
  btn-small tooltipped' data-position='bottom'
  data-tooltip='Eliminar' type='submit' name='eliminar'>
  <i class='material-icons'>delete</i>
  </button></form>

  <a href='multiple.php' 
  <button class='btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 left  
  btn-small tooltipped' data-position='bottom'
  data-tooltip='Volver' type='submit'>
  <i class='material-icons'>reply_all</i>
  </button></a>

 </td>
 </tr>";
 $i++;
 }
 }else
 echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
 <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
 ¡ Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro ! <a href='multiple.php'      class='teal-text darken-4'>volver</a>
 </h5>
 </div>";

  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He entendido tu planteamiento de la siguiente manera:

a. Dos tablas relacionadas por una clave, en este caso he usado `categoria_id`,

b. En la tabla `detalles_img` habría varias referencias de un mismo registro perteneciente a la tabla `detalles_categorias`

c. Necesitas ver en un sola fila cuántas ocurrencias hay de un registro de la tabla `detalles_categorias` en la tabla `detalles_img`.

Si he entendido bien lo que planteas, se resolvería de la manera siguiente:

Nota: He usado nombres de columnas más comprensibles para las relaciones. Pero si era lo que querías puedes adaptar el ejemplo.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b77bf/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE detalles_categorias
    (`id` int, `detalles_categorias` varchar(50), `categorias_id` int)
;

CREATE TABLE detalles_img
    (`id` int, `categorias_id` int, `detalles_img` varchar (50))
;



INSERT INTO detalles_categorias
    (`id`, `detalles_categorias`, `categorias_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Un detalle', 1),
    (2, 'Otro detalle', 2),
    (3, 'Otro más', 3)
;


INSERT INTO detalles_img
    (`id`, `categorias_id`, `detalles_img`)
VALUES
    (1, 1,'Img 1'),
    (2, 1,'Img 2'),
    (3, 1,'Img 3')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  dc.id, dc.detalles_categorias, dc.categorias_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(img.detalles_img SEPARATOR '---') AS images
FROM detalles_categorias dc
  INNER JOIN detalles_img img
  ON dc.categorias_id = img.categorias_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b77bf/7/0)**:

```
| id | detalles_categorias | categorias_id |                images |
|----|---------------------|---------------|-----------------------|
|  1 |          Un detalle |             1 | Img 1---Img 2---Img 3 |
```

Comment: ya lo adapte a lo que quiero gracias por el aporte [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f6034/4/0] pero ahora  mi duda para mostrar la imagen en le campo como seria porque me muestra la consulta bien pero menos la imagen

Comment: @yoclens Creo que la duda sobre la consulta SQL queda resuelta. No sé exactamente lo que tienes en la columna, si es una URL de una imagen, si es una imagen en sí, etc. Sea lo que sea, una vez obtenidos tus datos los puedes presentar de la siguiente manera: Supongamos que son rutas de imágenes lo que hay en la bd. Creas  un array con `explode` sobre la columna que tiene los diferentes valores y luego lees dicho array dentro de un `for each` o un `while`presentando cada imagen con `<img src="...." />`...

Comment: lo tengo de esta manera `<td align=center><img src='../galerias/$linea[imagen]' class=responsive-img circle center-align width=70px height=70px></td>` oye gracias por guiarme con el sql, agradecido

Comment: Si el resultado de la bd está en `$linea[imagen]` tienes que hacer un explode sobre esa variable, ejemplo: `$arr=explode('|',$linea['imagen']);`y luego lees `$arr`de esta manera: `foreach ($arr as $item) { echo '<td...><img src="../galerias/'.$item.'"/></td>';
}` No he puesto todo, es un ejemplo. En el explode he usado el símbolo `|` para mayor simplicidad, significa que si lo usas, debes cambiar el SEPARATOR del GROUP_CONCAT por `|` en lugar de `---`. Con esto podrás guiarte y si no lo resuelves mejor da esta pregunta por resuelta y pregunta de nuevo pues son 2 cosas distintas. Saludos.

Comment: pude solucionarlo anexo el código de como deberia quedar:  `<?php 
$detalles_img = explode("-", $linea['imagen']);
foreach ($detalles_img as $value) { 
echo ('<td colspan="2"><img src="../galerias/'.$value.'" class=responsive-img circle center-align width=50px height=50px/></td>') ; 
}
?>`